# Stepping stone algorithm in Operational Research

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, network-flow

I'm trying to solve a transportation cost problem using simplex tableu and the stepping stone algorithm.

I've done one iteration using the minimum cost method and this is the tableu I have obtained:

[image]

From here I've used the stepping stone algorithm and found that we could lower the cost even more if we increase the flow to $CW$.

The stepping stone algorithm showed that $CW = 3+3-3-4 = -1$ which shows cost could be lowered.

Where I'm confused is how much I should increase the flow in $CW$ by. In the solutions to the question I can see that apparently the max we can increase the flow by is $2$ but I'm not shown how this was obtained/decided.

If someone could show me how we decide the maximum we can increase the flow by it would really help since I will need to do more iterations of the stepping stone algorithm to find the optimal solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get an increase of 3 around the balanced loop BZ(+3), CZ(-3), CY(+3), AY(-3), AW(+3), BW(-3). Put a + on BZ then, using only occupied squares, you must put a - on CZ to balance the column, then a + on CY to balance the row and so on till you create a path back to BZ. Where there is a - you remove and the most you can remove is 3 sending AY to 0.

Comment: Oh wait, my bad I've put the wrong point to increase the flow, it's not $BZ$ it's $CW$ where we have the opportunity to lower costs, I'll edit my question

Comment: OK, now you have the simpler loop CW(+), AW(-), AY(+), CY(-).

Comment: This might help on the Stepping Stone Method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGKQXBL2YWo

Comment: Thanks, the video cleared everything up